# Loop and process over blocks of lines between two patterns in awk?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, text-processing

This is actually a continued version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or/38972737#38972737)question:

I have a file

```
1
2
PAT1
3    - first block
4
PAT2
5
6
PAT1
7    - second block
PAT2
8
9
PAT1
10    - third block
```

and I use `awk '/PAT1/{flag=1; next} /PAT2/{flag=0} flag'`
to extract the blocks of lines.

Extracting them works ok, but I'm trying to iterate over these blooks in a block-by-block fashion and do some processing with each block (e.g. save to file, process with other scripts etc.).

How can I construct such a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not very clear but you may do something like this:

```
awk '/PAT1/ {
   flag = 1
   ++n
   s = ""
   next
}
/PAT2/ {
   flag = 0
   printf "Processing record # %d =>\n%s", n, s
}
flag {
   s = s $0 ORS
}' file
```

```
Processing record # 1 =>
3    - first block
4
Processing record # 2 =>
7    - second block
```

Comment: This looks on the right track. What if instead of printing I'd like to save each block (the `s` variable in a separate file named like `record%d` ?

Comment: Of course you can do whatever you like. I used `print` just for demo purpose because question just said process a record. Just replace `printf` with `print s > ("record" n); close(("record" n))`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '/PAT1/!b;:a;N;/PAT2/!ba;e echo process:' -e 's/.*/echo "&"|wc/pe;p' file
```

Gather up the lines between `PAT1` and `PAT2` and process the collection.

In the example above, the literal `process:` is printed.

The command to print the result of the `wc` command for the collection is built and printed.

The result of the evaluation of the above command is printed.

N.B. The position of the `p` flag in the substitution command is critical. If the `p` is before the `e` flag the pattern space is printed before the evaluation, if the `p` flag is after the `e` flag the pattern space is post evaluation.